# while loop and milliseconds

Tags: mysql, bash, loops

I have been deleting records from my database based on their time stamp.

My query is simple

```
delete from calldetailrecord where StartTime between 1262321999000 AND 1309492799000;
```

1262321999000 = Thu Dec 31 2009 23:59:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

1296449999000 = Sun Jan 30 2011 23:59:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

For milliseconds, I have used:

http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/ to make my calculations

I wonder how can I make a while loop to delete the data month by month and stop when there is no more data.

Comment: Why do you need a loop here at all?

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder how can I make a while loop to delete month by month and it will stop when there are **no more data**.

If you want to delete all the data from a table use truncate command.

```
truncate calldetailrecord;
```

Simply a single `delete` will do it too

```
delete from calldetailrecord;
```

Comment: delete is significantly slower than truncate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get better performance this way:

```
Create table  new_table as select *  calldetailrecord where StartTime > 1309492799000

drop table calldetailrecord;
alter table new_table rename to calldetailrecord;
```

This gets around the issue of doing a row by row delete, which is going to be super slow.

Comment: Not everyone has `drop`, `create`, `alter` privileges. Usually users have `insert`, `update`, `delete` and `select` privileges.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im if that is the reason for down vote that is unique to say the least.  A proper DBA surely should not allow users to modify data that has to be backed up / archived.  Nor should a good DBA force developers to use inefficient methods for completing a task.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im users normally don't have delete privs, you must work in a very "loose" environment.

Comment: I am talking about the user credential people use in application to connect database. Not system users.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im applies both ways, especially to the delete function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do selective delete.
First prepare periods of time you want to delete, generate single query and than run it.

```
DELETE FROM calldetailrecord WHERE StartTime BETWEEN 1353897342 AND 1353897592 OR StartTime BETWEEN 1353897754 AND 1353897764;
```

You should use as minimum connections to db as possible.